# Getting Type Mismatch Errors, new to F#, how do I fix?

Tags: f#, paradigms

We are learning F# for one of my classes and using Visual Studio Code for it. I am doing a Homework Assignment and am getting the Type Mismatch Error for some of my functions. It is the only error but I don't know how to fix it. Any and all input or advice is appreciated, I am still learning so sorry if this is an easy fix. It is two series of code, but both have the same type of problem.

[The Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVVJ2.png)

Code 1

```
// Create a record type: Customer
type Customer = { Id: int; IsVip: bool; Credit: decimal }

// Real instances of customers
let customerVIP = { Id = 1; IsVip = true; Credit = 0.0M }
let customerSTD = { Id = 2; IsVip = false; Credit = 100.0M }

// Function 1: getPurchases
let getPurchases (customer: Customer) =
    if customer.Id % 2 = 0 then 120.0M
    else 80.0M

// Function 2: tryPromoteToVip
let tryPromoteToVip (purchase: decimal) (customer: Customer) =
    if purchase > 100.0M then { customer with IsVip = true }
    else customer

// Function 3: increaseCreditIfVip
let increaseCreditIfVip (customer: Customer) =
    if customer.IsVip then { customer with Credit = customer.Credit + 100.0M }
    else { customer with Credit = customer.Credit + 50.0M }

// Procedural
let upgradeCustomerProcedural customer =
    let purchases = getPurchases customer
    let updatedCustomer = tryPromoteToVip purchases customer
    increaseCreditIfVip updatedCustomer

// Nested
let upgradeCustomerNested customer =
    increaseCreditIfVip (tryPromoteToVip (getPurchases customer) customer)

// Composition operator
let upgradeCustomerComposed = getPurchases >> tryPromoteToVip >> increaseCreditIfVip

// Forward pipe operator
let upgradeCustomerPiped customer =
    customer
    |> getPurchases
    |> tryPromoteToVip customer
    |> increaseCreditIfVip

// Testing code
let assertVIP = upgradeCustomerComposed customerVIP = { Id = 1; IsVip = true; Credit = 100.0M }
let assertSTDtoVIP = upgradeCustomerComposed customerSTD = { Id = 2; IsVip = true; Credit = 200.0M }
let assertSTD = upgradeCustomerComposed { customerSTD with Id = 3; Credit = 50.0M } = { Id = 3; IsVip = false; Credit = 100.0M }
```

Code 2

```
open System

let cards = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]

// Define the drawCard function
let drawCard deck =
    match deck with
    | card::restOfDeck -> (restOfDeck, card)
    | [] -> ([], -1) // Assuming -1 indicates an empty deck

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let result =
        cards
        |> drawCard
        |> drawCard
        |> drawCard
        |> drawCard

    printfn "%A" result

    0

// Create an empty hand list
let hand = []

// Modify the drawCard function to accept a tuple of deck and hand
let drawCard (deck, hand) =
    match deck with
    | card::restOfDeck -> (restOfDeck, card::hand)
    | [] -> ([], hand)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let d, h =
        (cards, hand)
        |> drawCard
        |> drawCard

    printfn "Deck: %A Hand: %A" d h

    0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code 1:**

```ml
getPurchases >> tryPromoteToVip >> increaseCreditIfVip
```

The problem here is that `getPurchases` produces a purchase amount, but `tryPromoteToVip` expects two inputs: a purchase amount and a customer. As a result, the composed function `getPurchases >> tryPromoteToVip` expects two separate customers as input (`Customer -> Customer -> Customer`). I don't think that's what you want.

**Code 2:**

```ml
        cards
        |> drawCard
        |> drawCard
```

The problem here is similar: `drawCard` takes a deck as input and produces a tuple as output. That means that you can't send the result of `drawCard` directly into another call to `drawCard`.

---

In both cases, it looks like you have some context that you want to pass through the pipeline (a Customer, a deck of Cards). There are elegant ways to do this in F#, but they are probably too advanced for a beginner. For now, I suggest that each function in a pipeline should take a single value as input, and return a single value as output, to make it easier to compose them. If you really need to pass more than one value at a time, you can tuple them (like in `drawCard`), but then modify the next function to expect the same type of tuple as input.